# How to load content with ajax properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this .html page structure

```
<section id="1"> 
  </section>
<section id="2">
   </section>
<section id="3">
 </section>
<section id="4">
 </section>
```

Section 1 is a light weight page ,having not of much data .
Section 2 is moderately balanced.
Section 3 contains hd image (each image ~ 1.0mb)7 images.
Section 4 contains hdimages (each image ~ 1.0mb) near about 50 images.and 12 different instances of google map ,which takes so much of time to load the page. I have tried to reduce the image file size by some online image compressor (I cannot remove any image or map),but it still takes much time to load. Browsing through online i came to know about   [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajaxcomplete),i have tried to implement it in my page,but i dont know exactly how to use it ,
basically ,in the link they have demonstrated on loading the page after some mouse events.

My doubts :

How many time i can use the ajax loader thing ,only once in a page or any no of time i want to use ?(let say i have 12 maps to load ,so can I use it for 12 times? )

Is there a way to load the pages in parallel .i.e i can see my page 1 while page 2,page 3,and page4 is still loading.

Comment: You could do lazy loading  http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/ or jQuery Plugins: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2014/02/awesome-jquery-lazy-load-plugins.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try lazyloading. Instead of loading images at once, this will load the images step by step

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload